# Prevent Webkit View from allowing the screen to be pulled down exposing a gap at the top of the view

Tags: ios, webkit, swift4, xcode9

Is there a way to prevent a Webkit view from allowing the user to pull the view down past the top of the webpage, which creates a temporary gap between the top of the view and the actual web content? I want them to be able to scroll through the website, but when they're at the top of the webpage, I don't want them to be able to keep pulling it down. Is that possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The view has a boolean property called scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical and it needs to be set to false. My WebKit view is named mainWebPage so my line of code looked like this:

```
mainWebPage.scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```